# Django Database create_or_update error

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql, django-models

So the definition for the pcaps table is :

```
class Pcaps(models.Model):
    uuid = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    filehash = models.ForeignKey(Malwares)
    systemuuid = models.ForeignKey(ClonedSystem)
```

the definition for the malware table is:

```
class Malwares(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    filehash = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
```

the code from the views file is:

```
    Pcaps.objects.update_or_create(filename=pcapname, filehash=filehash, systemuuid=uuid)
```

the malware value is instantiated at:

```
    Malwares.objects.update_or_create(name=name, filehash=malwarehash)
```

the error I am getting is:

> invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'ed01ebfbc9eb5bbea545af4d01bf5f1071661840480439c6e5babe8e080e41aa'

(ed01... being the `filehash` value)

What error am I making here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting the *`filehash` value argument to a hash string*, while the `filehash` is a `ForeignKey` field which is an integer by default.

You've probably meant to first create `Malwares` record:

```
malware = Malwares.objects.create(name="name", filehash=malwarehash)
Pcaps.objects.update_or_create(filename=pcapname, filehash=malware, systemuuid=uuid)
```

Comment: Malwares.objects.update_or_create(name=name, filehash=malwarehash)

Comment: this is done elsewhere in the code, and the database is populated

Comment: @dipl0 okay, then, get the reference to the "updated or created" `Malwares` instance and use as a value for `filehash` argument when "updating or creating" `Pcaps`. Hope that helps.

Comment: filehashforeignkey = Malwares.objects.get(filehash=filehash)


        uuid = ClonedSystem.objects.get(uuid=uuid)

        Pcaps.objects.update_or_create(filename=pcapname, filehash=filehashforeignkey, systemuuid=uuid)